# Vim window padding along left edge

Tags: linux, vim, ubuntu

How can I add spacing along the left edge of my vim window? Text along the very left edge of a window makes it difficult to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen that problem myself, but that's probably because all text already has a margin from the left side because I display line numbers. Perhaps that's an option for you.

```
:set number
```

Comment: And if using vim 7.3 or higher (ok, for the moment this is the most up to date) `set rnu` is also good. Relative numbering is excellent for jk'ing.

Comment: you can also `set rnu` and `set number` (on separate lines) for both **relative numbering** as well as **line numbers**.  Line number will, however, be displayed only on the `line` on which the `cursor` currently is.  All other `lines` will have `relative numbering` to that `line`.